# Getting Error while trying to create a nuget for a Xamarin Android Binding Library Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac, xamarin-binding

So I'm trying to build a Nuget Package for an Android Binding Library on Xamarin Mac and I'm getting an error like this

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Bindings.targets(5,5):
>   Error MSB4044: The "GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" task was not
>   given a value for the required parameter "DesignTimeBuild". (MSB4044)

Not sure what to do with this, google a lot, checked StackOverflow couldn't find anything related to this specific error, any inputs would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you have added all the errors because this seems to be just one line which seems incomplete, can you add the full error from your output screen

Comment: @G.hakim this is all there is, is there something specific you're looking for ??

Comment: I am looking for further information can you add the lines above this from your output window?

Comment: @G.hakim, there's nothing above this, it's just one error

Comment: maybe you could do it follow this procedure: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/105125/not-able-to-create-a-nuget-package